# “out loud”: is it hyphenated or not?

Tags: grammar

Does “out loud” require a hyphen?  As in “think out loud.”  What do you think?  I think it does not.  I noticed that it is commonly used without one.  Even so, it bothers me.

Answer (score 2):

No hyphen according to the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> **out loud** — aloud; audibly: *she laughed out loud*.

Comment: You would hyphenate it as part of a compound adjective, though: *Those were just her out-loud remarks."

Comment: @Robusto: Thanks for that one. I was just trying to imagine when it *would* be hyphenated. Basically, not very often.